# Third party packages seems to be searched in $GOROOT

Tags: go

I created my first go project and try to use some external package

```
import terminal "github.com/wayneashleyberry/terminal-dimensions"
```

My project is in `/home/noname/Workspace/go/src/proj/proj.go`

go env looks fine

```
$ go env
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN="/home/noname/Workspace/go/bin"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/noname/Workspace/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/lib/go-1.8"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/go-1.8/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build163861736=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
```

but when I try to run it I see

```
$ go run proj.go 
# command-line-arguments
/usr/lib/go-1.8/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: cannot open file /usr/lib/go-1.8/pkg/linux_amd64/github.com/wayneashleyberry/terminal-dimensions.a: open /usr/lib/go-1.8/pkg/linux_amd64/github.com/wayneashleyberry/terminal-dimensions.a: no such file or directory
```

This happens with any third-party library not necessary this one and I don't understand why. Seems like go searches for third-party package in `$GOROOT`  while package actually located exactly where docs says it should be

```
$ file $GOPATH/pkg/linux_amd64/github.com/wayneashleyberry/terminal-dimensions.a 
/home/noname/Workspace/go/pkg/linux_amd64/github.com/wayneashleyberry/terminal-dimensions.a: current ar archive
```

Sorry for newbie question

EDIT:

```
$ go run -x proj.go 
WORK=/tmp/go-build340740598
mkdir -p $WORK/_/home/noname/Workspace/go/src/proj/shell/_obj/
mkdir -p $WORK/_/home/noname/Workspace/go/src/proj/
cd /home/noname/Workspace/go/src/proj/shell
/usr/lib/go-1.8/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/compile -o $WORK/_/home/noname/Workspace/go/src/proj/shell.a -trimpath $WORK -p _/home/noname/Workspace/go/src/proj/shell -complete -buildid efa1c0a0a5d82b27eb41cb592f4cb626ff98c64f -D _/home/noname/Workspace/go/src/proj/shell -I $WORK -I /home/noname/Workspace/go/pkg/linux_amd64 -pack ./input.go ./shell.go
mkdir -p $WORK/command-line-arguments/_obj/
mkdir -p $WORK/command-line-arguments/_obj/exe/
cd /home/noname/Workspace/go/src/proj
/usr/lib/go-1.8/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/compile -o $WORK/command-line-arguments.a -trimpath $WORK -p main -complete -buildid b280c68738f8469c481a1c4c407f43b16a476fdc -D _/home/noname/Workspace/go/src/proj -I $WORK -I "" -pack ./proj.go
cd .
/usr/lib/go-1.8/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link -o $WORK/command-line-arguments/_obj/exe/proj -L $WORK -L "" -w -extld=gcc -buildmode=exe -buildid=b280c68738f8469c481a1c4c407f43b16a476fdc $WORK/command-line-arguments.a
# command-line-arguments
/usr/lib/go-1.8/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: cannot open file /usr/lib/go-1.8/pkg/linux_amd64/github.com/wayneashleyberry/terminal-dimensions.a: open /usr/lib/go-1.8/pkg/linux_amd64/github.com/wayneashleyberry/terminal-dimensions.a: no such file or directory
```

EDIT2:

```
$ go list -f {{.Dir}} github.com/wayneashleyberry/terminal-dimensions
/home/noname/Workspace/go/src/github.com/wayneashleyberry/terminal-dimensions
```

Comment: Just to make sure, how did you install the third party libraries? `go get github.com/wayneashleyberry/terminal-dimensions` ?

Comment: Look at `go run -x proj.go` and post the output here. Maybe there is something, that helps to find an answer.

Comment: @putu, yes, exactly

Comment: How if you remove the `GOBIN` environment variable? I suppose you set both `GOPATH` and `GOBIN` in your bash env. Just remove the `GOBIN` part, then run `source` to update the env. If it's not the case, just ignore my comment.

Comment: @putu I manually ran `unset GOBIN`, now go env shows `GOBIN=""`, but `go run` result is exactly the same

Comment: Try `go list -f {{.Dir}} github.com/wayneashleyberry/terminal-dimensions` and post the output.

Comment: @Krom, edited my question again. Also, Is it important that i have a subpackage inside my `proj` and i'm importing `wayneashleyberry/terminal-dimensions` inside it?

Comment: Do you make symbolic-link between GOPATH/GOROOT?

Comment: @mattn, No, It's to different folders, no symlink

Comment: It's quite strange behavior. How did you install `go`? from source or binary? If possible, try install another version of go. You can use [Go Version Manager](https://github.com/moovweb/gvm) to easily manage and install multiple version of go, and it will be installed under `~/.gvm`.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't remember Ho did I install go, I'm pretty sure I installed it from some ppa. I'll try to reinstall it

Comment: I purged go and intalled it using `snap`.  It helped for some reason! Thank you!